# How can I stop the click on the tooltip of sorter in antd table columns?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, tooltip, antd, tablesorter

```
  <Column
     id={item?.dataIndex}
     {...item}
     key={item?.dataIndex}
     title={item?.title}
     columnWidth={item?.width}
     inputType={item?.addRowType}
     dataIndex={item?.dataIndex}
     className={item?.className}
     sorter={
       isSorter || item?.isSorter
         ? ""
         : {
           multiple: index,
           compare: (a, b) => a?.dataIndex - b?.dataIndex,
         }
    }
     editable={item?.editable}
     render={(value) => colRenderData(item, value, editMode)}
   />
```

In this code how can I handle the click on the tooltip of the sorter? As the tooltip is clickable in antd table. I need to handle the click how can I handle this?

I tried the **showSorterTooltip** prop but this will hide the tooltip, I need to show the tooltip but in disabled mode or it should not be clickable